# biblatex driver for journals without real page numbers

Tags: biblatex

Some open access journals like JHEP don't have a real page number, altough they export one, see:

http://iopscience.iop.org/1126-6708/2001/01/010/

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[]{biblatex}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{refs.bib}
@article{1126-6708-2001-01-010,
  author={Gennaro Corcella and Ian G. Knowles and Giuseppe Marchesini and Stefano Moretti and Kosuke Odagiri and Peter
Richardson and Michael H. Seymour and Bryan R. Webber},
  title={HERWIG 6: an event generator for hadron emission reactions with interfering gluons (including supersymmetric processes)},
  journal={Journal of High Energy Physics},
  volume={2001},
  number={01},
  pages={010},
  url={http://stacks.iop.org/1126-6708/2001/i=01/a=010},
  year={2001},
  abstract={HERWIG is a general-purpose Monte Carlo event generator, which includes the simulation of hard lepton-lepton, lepton-hadron and hadron-hadron scattering and soft hadron-hadron collisions in one package. It uses the parton-shower approach for initial- and final-state QCD radiation, including colour coherence effects and azimuthal correlations both within and between jets. This article updates the description of HERWIG published in 1992, emphasising the new features incorporated since then. These include, in particular, the matching of first-order matrix elements with parton showers, a more correct treatment of heavy quark decays, and a wide range of new processes, including many predicted by the Minimal Supersymmetric Standard Model, with the option of R-parity violation. At the same time we offer a brief review of the physics underlying HERWIG, together with details of the input and control parameters and the output data, to provide a self-contained guide for prospective users of the program.}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\addbibresource{refs.bib}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

This does not render well with biblatex's `article` driver, because the "010" is regarded as a real page number. What do you suggest to remove the "p." and maybe put the "010" in paranthesis?

[image: screenshot demonstrating the problem]

Comment: I understand your concern--you want your sources to be properly referenced--but that's really a question for the editor of that journal.

Comment: Ideas
1.) (obvious) delete pages for those refs (will anyone be able to use the fake pages to actually locate the article ? 
2.) Invent a new field, e.g. `fakepages` and then modify the bibliography style file to render it properly
3.) Invent a new driver, e.g. `noparticle` (you can probably copy the article one wholesale and just modify it) and give each JHEP reference that driver.
I do not have time to provide a proper answer (sorry), but you can find the 'how to` do each of those is covered in the `biblatex` manual,

Answer (score 4):

You can test the first token of the input of `pages`. If it is zero you can use `\mkbibbrackets`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[]{biblatex}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{refs.bib}
@article{1126-6708-2001-01-010,
  author={Gennaro Corcella and Ian G. Knowles and Giuseppe Marchesini and Stefano Moretti and Kosuke Odagiri and Peter
Richardson and Michael H. Seymour and Bryan R. Webber},
  title={HERWIG 6: an event generator for hadron emission reactions with interfering gluons (including supersymmetric processes)},
  journal={Journal of High Energy Physics},
  volume={2001},
  number={01},
  pages={010},
  url={http://stacks.iop.org/1126-6708/2001/i=01/a=010},
  year={2001},
  abstract={HERWIG is a general-purpose Monte Carlo event generator, which includes the simulation of hard lepton-lepton, lepton-hadron and hadron-hadron scattering and soft hadron-hadron collisions in one package. It uses the parton-shower approach for initial- and final-state QCD radiation, including colour coherence effects and azimuthal correlations both within and between jets. This article updates the description of HERWIG published in 1992, emphasising the new features incorporated since then. These include, in particular, the matching of first-order matrix elements with parton showers, a more correct treatment of heavy quark decays, and a wide range of new processes, including many predicted by the Minimal Supersymmetric Standard Model, with the option of R-parity violation. At the same time we offer a brief review of the physics underlying HERWIG, together with details of the input and control parameters and the output data, to provide a self-contained guide for prospective users of the program.}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\addbibresource{refs.bib}

\usepackage{expl3}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\DeclareFieldFormat{pages}{
  \str_if_eq_x:nnTF { \tl_head:n { #1 } } { 0 } %test first token = 0
    { \mkbibbrackets{#1} }%true
    { \mkpageprefix[bookpagination]{#1} }%false
}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]